# Warning: Illegal string offset

Tags: php, foreach

Estou tentando mostrar no relatório o resultado de um `INNER JOIN` de 3 tabelas, guardo os 3 valores em um `array` e faço um `foreach` para percorrer todos os registros, mas aparece o seguinte erro:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'Frota'
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'NomeCompleto'
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'Descricao'

Meu `foreach` está assim:

```
<?php foreach ($acessos as $acesso) : ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $acesso['Frota']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $acesso['NomeCompleto']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $acesso['Descricao']; ?></td>
    <td class="actions text-right">
        <a href="Editar.php?Codigo=<?php echo $acesso['Codigo']; ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Inserir Entrada</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Esse é código que faz a consulta no banco de dados:

```
function INNERJOIN (){

    $database = open_database();
    $found = null;

    $sql = "SELECT tblacesso.Codigo, tblfrota.Frota, tblpessoa.NomeCompleto, tbldestino.Descricao FROM tblacesso INNER JOIN tblfrota ON(tblacesso.FrotaID = tblfrota.Codigo) INNER JOIN tblpessoa ON(tblacesso.MotoristaID = tblpessoa.Codigo) INNER JOIN tbldestino ON(tblacesso.DestinoID = tbldestino.Codigo)";
    $result = $database->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $found = $result->fetch_assoc();
    }    
    close_database($database);
    return $found;
}
```

Usei um `var_dump($acessos);` para verificar o tipo de dados da minha variável e apareceu o seguinte resultado:

```
array (size=3)
'Frota' => string '9999' (length=4)
'NomeCompleto' => string 'Jean C. Galhardi' (length=16)
'Descricao' => string 'Palmares' (length=8)//////
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Essa publicação deve ser uma "duplicata" de algumas várias, nem sei se deveria responder isto, porque a resposta está no próprio erro.*

O que está ocorrendo é porque o `foreach()` está fazendo com que apenas uma chave seja acessada por vez.

Você tem isso:

```
$array = ['Frota' => 9999, 'NomeCompleto' => 'Jean', 'Descricao' => 'Palmares'];
```

Se fizer isto:

```
foreach($array as $valor){
     echo $valor;
}
```

O `$item` será "9999" depois "Jean" e depois "Palmares" e não um array.

Em um resumo, *da maneira que consigo explicar simplificadamente*, essa função vai fazer com que ele obtenha cada chave da array, ou seja o *loop* é por chave, neste caso possui três chaves, cada "vez que ele roda" irá pegar um valor da respectiva chave.

Para usar como você quer você precisa fazer um array dentro do outro, dessa forma:

```
$array = [
    0 => ['Frota' => 9999, 'NomeCompleto' => 'Jean', 'Descricao' => 'Palmares']
];
```

Dessa forma o `0 =>`, *que pode ser omitido ou ter outro nome*, é a chave, portanto usar o mesmo `foreach` fará com que o `$valor` seja uma array (que contem Frota, NomeCompleto, Descricao).

Logo, usando esta nova array com isto (que está usando):

```
foreach($array as $item){
    echo $item['Frota'];
    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo $item['NomeCompleto'];
}
```

Funcionará normalmente, porque ele irá obter o valor da chave `0` que é a array, esta array será acessada por `$item['Frota']` por exemplo.

*Se não mantenha array como está e apenas remova o `foreach`, funcionará normalmente.*

---

Altere isto:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  $found = $result->fetch_assoc();
}
```

Para isto:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($linha = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     $found[] = $linha;
  }
}
```

O resto permanece como esta, isto irá criar um array dentro da outra, corrigindo o problema do `foreach` o único cuidado é que se não for encontrado irá retornar `null`, devido ao `$found = null;`.

Uma outra opção, **se tiver utilizando [Mysqlnd](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqlnd.php)** é utilizar:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  $found = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta... sou iniciante em PHP, me ajuda a esquematizar, você colocou o código espalhado para explicar e eu acabei ficando perdido, como ficarei o código?

Comment: Precisa porque pode ter mais de um registro para aparecer na tela.

Comment: Editei minha pergunta com o código que faz o JOIN.
Eu uso o foreach para listar os resultados.

Comment: O `fetch_assoc` sempre retornará uma única linha, somente utilizando loop ou o `fetch_all` irá retornar todas, irei editar a resposta.

Comment: Funcionou... obrigado pela disponibilidade.